# XSD assert : Multiply all values in sequence

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, assert

I have an xml document which looks like follows:

```
<Output>
    <Integer start="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
    <Dimensions>
        <Dimension value="2"/>
        <Dimension value="3"/>
    </Dimensions>
</Output>
```

I also have an XSD file which defines the corresponding structure. The start attribute is defined as a list of integer. 
Inside this XSD file I want to have an assertion which check if the number of values in this list is equal to the multiplication of all value attributes of the Dimension elements. In this case 2 * 3 = 6 values have to be defined in start.

It would be something like

```
<xs:assert test="count(data(./Integer/@start)) = multiply(./Dimensions/Dimension/@value) "/>
```

My problem is how to write the multiply similar to sum, but with multiplication instead of addition. Is there any possibility to add functions to the XSD document? Or is there a possibility to rewrite the assert test to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

XSD 1.1 assertions are limited to XPath 2.0 which makes this difficult; there's no access to the XPath 3.1 [`fold-left()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-fold-left) function, or to user-defined functions (which would allow recursion).

Some XSD 1.1 processor might lift this restriction (you can configure Saxon to allow XPath 3.1) but that's going beyond the spec.

If you're prepared to limit the number of Dimensions you can do it like this

```
number(if (exists(Dimension[1])) then Dimension[1]/@value else 1) *
number(if (exists(Dimension[2])) then Dimension[2]/@value else 1) *
number(if (exists(Dimension[3])) then Dimension[3]/@value else 1) *
... etc
```

But I don't think there's a general solution using pure XSD 1.1 + XPath 2.0.

With XPath 3.1 enabled, you could do

```
count(...) = fold-left(Dimension/@value, 1, 
               function($total, $next){$total*number($next)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking for multiply function that works with lists/sequences.

Since there is no such built-in function afaik, this requires a user-defined recursive function (in XQuery's functional programming land) like that:

```
declare function local:rec-multiply($seq, $count) {
  if(empty($seq)) then ()
  else
    let $prod  := $seq[1], 
        $count := $count * $prod
    return (
      <count>{ $count }</count>,
      local:rec-multiply($seq[position() > 1], $count)
    )
};

count(tokenize(//Integer/@start, '\s')) 
  = local:rec-multiply(//Dimension/@value, 1)[last()]
```

[Online Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3COutput%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CInteger%20start%3D%220%200%200%200%200%200%200%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDimensions%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDimension%20value%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDimension%20value%3D%223%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDimensions%3E%0A%3C%2FOutput%3E&=%200&extract=declare%20function%20local%3Arec-multiply(%24seq%2C%20%24count)%20%7B%0A%20%20if(empty(%24seq))%20then%20()%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%24prod%20%20%3A%3D%20%24seq%5B1%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24count%20%3A%3D%20%24count%20*%20%24prod%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccount%3E%7B%20%24count%20%7D%3C%2Fcount%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20local%3Arec-multiply(%24seq%5Bposition()%20%3E%201%5D%2C%20%24count)%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Acount(tokenize(%2F%2FInteger%2F%40start%2C%20'%5Cs'))%20%0A%20%20%3D%20local%3Arec-multiply(%2F%2FDimension%2F%40value%2C%201)%5Blast()%5D&=declare%20function%20local%3Arec-multiply(%24seq%2C%20%24count)%20%7B%0A%20%20if(empty(%24seq))%20then%20()%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%24prod%20%20%3A%3D%20%24seq%5B1%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24count%20%3A%3D%20%24count%20*%20%24prod%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccount%3E%7B%20%24count%20%7D%3C%2Fcount%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20local%3Arec-multiply(%24seq%5Bposition()%20%3E%201%5D%2C%20%24count)%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Acount(tokenize(%2F%2FInteger%2F%40start%2C%20'%5Cs'))%20%0A%20%20%3D%20local%3Arec-multiply(%2F%2FDimension%2F%40value%2C%201)%5Blast()%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xquery3)

Caveat: This code requires XQuery 3+ and common XSD processors only support XPath 2.0 (actually often only a subset). If you lift that restriction, you can go with XQuery's fold-left/right functions as well, as mentioned by Michael Kay.

However, in the end, it's most likely much easier to simply extract those values and perform the multiplication & validation in your general purpose programming language.

Comment: Sadly, there's no access to XQuery user-defined functions within an XSD 1.1 assertion.